# Cannot change value of a QSlider from a QWidget

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5

I am trying to change the value of a QWidget from another QWidget, but nothing is happening. I am using this line to call the changeValue function from each Filter object:

```
self.filter1.valueChanged.connect(self.filter1.changeValue)
```

I have put the `print(value)` statement inside the changeValue method to see if the method is being called, but it is not.

This is my code:

```
import sys
import numpy as np
import cv2
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap, QImage
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QLabel, QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout,
                             QApplication, QPushButton, QSlider,
                             QFileDialog)


class Filter(QSlider):
    """Common base for all filters"""
    defaultK = 3
    filterCount = 0

    def __init__(self):
        super(Filter, self).__init__()

        # Variable for the constant of the OpenCV filter
        self.k = 3

        # Label for the slider
        self.k_lbl = QLabel(str(self.k))

        # Increase the number of filters created
        Filter.filterCount += 1

        # Slider for the first OpenCV filter, with min, max, default and step values
        self.thresh_sld = QSlider(Qt.Horizontal, self)
        self.thresh_sld.setFocusPolicy(Qt.NoFocus)
        self.thresh_sld.setMinimum(3)
        self.thresh_sld.setMaximum(51)
        self.thresh_sld.setValue(self.k)
        self.thresh_sld.setSingleStep(2)

    def changeValue(self, value):
        # Function for setting the value of k1

        print(value)

        if value % 2 == 1:
            self.k = value
        else:
            self.k = value + 1

        self.thresh_sld.setValue(self.k)
        self.k_lbl.setText(str(self.k))

class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

        self.filter1 = Filter()
        self.filter2 = Filter()

        # Function sending the slider signal to the processing function
        self.filter1.valueChanged.connect(self.filter1.changeValue)
        self.filter2.valueChanged.connect(self.filter2.changeValue)

        # Creates the main layout (vertical)
        v_main_lay = QVBoxLayout()
        # Adds the sliders and their labels to the bottom of the main layout
        v_main_lay.addWidget(self.filter1.k_lbl)
        v_main_lay.addWidget(self.filter1.thresh_sld)
        v_main_lay.addWidget(self.filter2.k_lbl)
        v_main_lay.addWidget(self.filter2.thresh_sld)

        # Sets the main layout
        self.setLayout(v_main_lay)

        # Sets the geometry, position, window title and window default mode
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 350, 300)
        self.setWindowTitle('Review')
        self.showMaximized()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are inheriting from `QSlider` and at the same time you are creating within that class an attribute called thresh_sld, and this is the element that is showing in the view, but not connected to `changeValue`, the slider that is connected to `ChangeValue` is the `Filter` class Slider.

Use simple solution is to connect the signal of the attribute `thresh_sld` to the slot provided, you must change the following:

```
self.filter1.valueChanged.connect(self.filter1.changeValue)
self.filter2.valueChanged.connect(self.filter2.changeValue)
```

to:

```
self.filter1.thresh_sld.valueChanged.connect(self.filter1.changeValue)
self.filter2.thresh_sld.valueChanged.connect(self.filter2.changeValue)
```

A more elegant solution is to change the Filter base class from `QSlider` to `QWidget`, and add the label and `QSlider` to its layout.

```
class Filter(QWidget):
    """Common base for all filters"""
    defaultK = 3
    filterCount = 0

    def __init__(self):
        super(Filter, self).__init__()
        lay = QVBoxLayout(self)

        # Variable for the constant of the OpenCV filter
        self.k = 3

        # Label for the slider
        self.k_lbl = QLabel(str(self.k))

        # Increase the number of filters created
        Filter.filterCount += 1

        # Slider for the first OpenCV filter, with min, max, default and step values
        self.thresh_sld = QSlider(Qt.Horizontal, self)
        self.thresh_sld.setFocusPolicy(Qt.NoFocus)
        self.thresh_sld.setMinimum(3)
        self.thresh_sld.setMaximum(51)
        self.thresh_sld.setValue(self.k)
        self.thresh_sld.setSingleStep(2)
        self.thresh_sld.valueChanged.connect(self.changeValue)

        lay.addWidget(self.k_lbl)
        lay.addWidget(self.thresh_sld)

    def changeValue(self, value):
        # Function for setting the value of k1

        print(value)

        if value % 2 == 1:
            self.k = value
        else:
            self.k = value + 1

        self.thresh_sld.setValue(self.k)
        self.k_lbl.setText(str(self.k))

class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

        self.filter1 = Filter()
        self.filter2 = Filter()

        # Creates the main layout (vertical)
        v_main_lay = QVBoxLayout()
        # Adds the sliders and their labels to the bottom of the main layout
        v_main_lay.addWidget(self.filter1)
        v_main_lay.addWidget(self.filter2)

        # Sets the main layout
        self.setLayout(v_main_lay)

        # Sets the geometry, position, window title and window default mode
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 350, 300)
        self.setWindowTitle('Review')
        self.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This was indeed the problem. And thanks for the tip on the layout organization, it became much better.